# Removing i:th nodes from a general tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I want to delete n:th leaves of a general tree and when there is no more leave on the tree, get an error. 
I have this code:

```
entferne :: NBaum a -> NBaum a
entferne (NBlatt i) int | i == int
                            | otherwise = NBlatt i
entferne (BKnoten left right) int = BKnoten (entferne left 
int) (entferne right int)
```

But i get this error:

```
parse error on input `|`
```

I checked the shift did all the spaces with space and still get it.

Comment: That’s just not going to work, unless you mean for `entferne` to call `error` and crash the program. There’s no way for it to return an error, unless you change it to `NBaum -> Maybe NBaum`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
entferne (NBlatt i) int | i == int
```

lacks a returned value for that case. It should be

```
entferne (NBlatt i) int | i == int = <some value here>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the line

```
entferne (NBlatt i) int | i == int
```

is a pattern guard.  It needs to be followed with `=` and then an expression to compute that case.